# Script for sending email attachments from google script

Tags: attachment

Here is the script for the button i am working on. the script creates the pdf and folder, Sends email but doesn't grab the attachment.

I have removed the file id and url ect.

The main section i am having problems is the attachment.

Really appreciate any help with this one.

```
function getpdf2(){
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  //make pdf
  var theurl = ''
  + ''  //the file ID
  + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&size=LETTER'
  + '&portrait=true'
  + '&fitw=true'       
  + '&top_margin=0.50'              
  + '&bottom_margin=0.50'          
  + '&left_margin=0.50'             
  + '&right_margin=0.50'           
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
  + '&pagenum=false'
  + '&gridlines=false'
  + '&fzr=FALSE'      
  + '&gid='
  + '';       //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } 
});
  var fileid = DriveApp.createFile(docurl.getBlob()).setName('Quote mike.pdf').getId();
  //var blob = spreadsheetFile.getAs('application/pdf');
  var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName('Quote mike.pdf');
  var pdf = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName('Quote mike.pdf'); 
 var filetodel = DriveApp.getFileById(fileid);
 DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder("mike");  //comment if folder exists
 // if folder exists use next 
 if (DriveApp.getFoldersByName("mike").hasNext()){
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("mike").next();
filetodel.makeCopy(folder);

var address = Browser.inputBox('Enter Email Address', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

//function sendEmailWithAttachments(){
 //var fileid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  //getAs(MimeType.PDF);
MailApp.sendEmail({to:address,
                 subject: "QUOTE",
                 body:"Thank You!!",
                 attachments: [fileid[0].getAs(MimeType.pdf)]
  })
  DriveApp.removeFile(filetodel);
```

}
}